# Vim: contradictory key-mappings in a setting with long soft-wrapped lines PLUS reletivenumber

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

It is a headache to have the following two options enabled at the same time:

```
" Line numbering.
set number
set relativenumber

" The master setting (with wrapping)
set wrap
set linebreak
set nolist " list disables linebreak
set textwidth=0
set wrapmargin=0
set formatoptions+=l "No reformatting while typing on the exciting line.
```

Relative line numbers are very neat and helpful, however, when my texts come with long lines that have been wrapped, "jumping down by 5 lines" and "moving within the long wrapped line" become a contradictory set of tasks.

In order to move around the long wrapped lines, I would need to use the following mapping.

```
nnoremap  j gj
nnoremap  k gk
vnoremap  j gj
vnoremap  k gk
```

However, jumping downward by 5 lines can no longer be triggered by `5j`. I should type `#j` where `#` = the number of "visually" wrapped lines between the current line and the 5th line downward.

Is there a solution to this contradiction in key-mapping? Will there be a plug-in that numbers the softly wrapped lines? This is the only solution that I can think of.t

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no option to enable "softly-wrapped relativenumbers", and it wouldn't be very useful, as offsets are not only used for `j` / `k` navigation, but also for all sorts of other commands, and `:[range]`, too, and these will continue to be addressed by physical, hard lines.

Before `'relativenumber'` was introduced, there was the [RltvNmbr.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2351), which emulated that option using the signs column. You could try to modify that to accommodate your idea. Considering the mentioned limitations and that the plugin used a messy workaround, I'd rather suggest you define the opposite mappings, too:

```
nnoremap  gj j
nnoremap  gk k
vnoremap  gj j
vnoremap  gk k
```

With that, you can use the quick `j` etc. commands to easily navigate wrapped lines, and for the (fewer) occasions where a relative jump is wanted, use `[N]gj`.